# Прослушивать два порта для двух разные Swagger UI ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, swagger

Всем привет,
У меня есть web приложение на ASP .net Core (C#), которое сейчас прослушивает один порт. По адресу и этому одному порту выдает Swagger, хочу чтобы приложение начало слушать второй порт и по этому порту выдавался другой Swagger (ну и собственно для второго порта свои контроллеры и Swagger). Подскажите как такое реализовать ?

Comment: А зачем вам разные порты? Запустить несколько копий сервера с разными настройками не помогает?

Comment: @aepot, пока что рассматриваю ситуацию, когда запускаю один сервер и он работает с двумя портами, в общем нужно второе API рядом с тем которое уже есть

Comment: Почему вам нужна именно одна копия сервера? Какие преимущества это дает?

Comment: разобрался, решение простое, но не тривиальное, по роуту генерятся новые swagger файлы